# Exact potential outside a spherical shell

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, gauss-law

I am trying to determine the exact scalar potential due to a surface charge distribution of a spherical shell of Radius $R$ at radius $r > R$.

The surface charge distribution is
$\sigma \left ( \vec{r} ' \right )=k \cos\left ( \theta ' \right )$

Here, $$V\left ( \vec{r} \right )=\frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon }\oint _{s~=~{\partial v }} \frac{\sigma \left ( \vec{r'} \right )}{\left \| \vec{r}-\vec{r'} \right \|}~\mathrm ds'$$

where $\vec{r}$ is the distance vector from the origin to the charge distribution non the surface of the spherical shell a distance $R$ from the origin
and 
$\vec{r'} $is the distance vector from the origin to a point at a distance r>R from the origin.

Imagine a vector $\vec{r}'$ pointing along the $z$-axis and an angle $\theta' $ between another vector $\vec{r} $

[image]

we get $$\frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon }\int_{\theta'=~0}^{\pi}\int_{\phi'=~0}^{2 \pi}\frac{\cos\left ( \theta' \right )}{\left \| \vec{r}-\vec{r'} \right \|}~\mathrm da'$$

Note that for any two unit vectors $\hat{v}$ and $\hat{v}'
\hat{v}\cdot  \hat{v}'=Cos\left ( \theta \right )$

I referred to the solution after seeing no progression.

It says that $\hat{z}\hat{r}'=\cos\left ( \theta' \right )\;.$

I don't understand how this is at all possible. On a spherical coordinate there is no $\hat{z}$!
Can someone shed some light as to what is going on with the physics?

Edit: Solution to question

[image]

[image]

Comment: Google **Separation of Variables and a Spherical Shell with Surface Charge jacobi.luc.edu › SoV**  it's a pdf and I **think** it might be a bit more advanced than you have written, but give it a shot. If that's not suitable, **keep googling**

Comment: How far do you wish to simplify? Because without a few elements of symmetry, you wont be able to simplify much further.

Comment: I don't understand how this question doesn't fit the guidelines of  "question related to  physics"
Clearly, there are 'many' ways for which $Cos(\theta')$ can be achieved but exactly which dot product pairing of unit vector is determined by the physics in question.

Comment: The question does not involve separation of variables. 
@count_to_10
I have edited the op.

Comment: @Lelouch OP edited

Comment: I'll like to add that if I were to utilise the law of cosine at the outset, the problem would have been solved with ease.
This ease stems from the fact that there exists a magnitude over the difference in position vectors in the denominator.
However, the solution takes a detour which adds to the confusion, namely:
The distance vector from the origin to a point r>R outside the spherical shell is given as in the $\hat{z}$ direction by the solution. I cartesian coordinate, I would be in full agreement but in Spherical coordinate these is no $\hat{z}$ to speak of.